# Efficiently Taking the Sums of all Pairs of Elements from a Set

Tags: time-complexity, summation

I have a set of numbers and I want to find the sums of all possible pairs of elements. With the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ for example, I would want $\{1+2, 1+3, 2+3\}$ as my answer. I could do that in n^2 time complexity by starting at the first element and adding all the other elements to it one-by-one and then moving to the second element, but is there an algorithm that would compute all the sums in a better time complexity?

Comment: Since the output could be of size $\Omega(n^2)$ for a set of size $n$, I doubt there is a better algorithm for the general case.

Comment: @Nathaniel, I encourage you to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it, and so the question is treated as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output could be of size $\Omega(n^2)$ for a set of size n, I doubt there is a better algorithm for the general case.

For example, consider $S = \{1, 2, 4, …, 2^{n-1}\}$. For $\{i, j\} \neq \{k, \ell\}$, $2^i+2^j \neq 2^k+2^{\ell}$, so the output will be of size $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.